# How to Sort an array with dates (Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

Keep getting error Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date[]'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.

```
const Date: string[] = ['April 1, 2017 10:39 PM', 'April 1, 2017 10:39 PM', 'January 1, 2018 9:39 PM', 'February 11, 2019 9:39 PM', 'April 1, 2019 10:39 PM']

const sDates = Utils.sDates(Date, false)

console.log(sDates)
```

```
Function to SortDate

export namespace Utils {
export function sDates(items: Date[], isDescending?: boolean): Date[] {
        let sDateArr: Date[] = [...items];

        if (isDescending) {
            sDateArr.sort(function (dateA: Date, dateB: Date) { return +dateB - +dateA });
        } else {
            sDateArr.sort(function (dateA: Date, dateB: Date) { return +dateA - +dateB});
        }
        return sDateArr;
    }
}
```

Comment: because your variable named `Date` (please change this) is type `string[]` because it's an array of `string`s

Comment: Hi @Samathingamajig but this does not resolve the issue...i knew it was a type string. thanks

Comment: Convert the strings into real date objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert all the dates from you array to Date objects

```js
// rename your array to avoid conflict with the native Date object
const dates: string[] = ['April 1, 2017 10:39 PM', 'April 1, 2017 10:39 PM', 'January 1, 2018 9:39 PM', 'February 11, 2019 9:39 PM', 'April 1, 2019 10:39 PM']

const sDates = Utils.sDates(
  dates.map((date) => new Date(date)),
  false
);

console.log(sDates)
```